# Si dices que "te está dando la sombra", ¿"la sombra" es sujeto o complemento directo?

Tags: gramática, complemento-directo, sujeto

Me ha surgido una duda que igual puede ser muy tonta, pero os la comento a ver qué os parece. Ayer mismo estaba paseando con mi hijo mayor y nos estaba dando el sol, a lo que él se quejó. Le dije que aguantara hasta llegar donde unos árboles que allí nos iba a dar la sombra.

Y entonces pensé: ¿qué papel juega "la sombra" ahí?

Viendo las acepciones de "dar", veo que hay una acepción intransitiva que encaja con la frase similar "me da el sol":

> 42. intr. Dicho del sol, del aire, etc.: Incidir sobre alguna superficie.

En la frase "me da el sol", parece claro que el sol es el sujeto de la acción "incidir sobre una superficie". Pero para la frase "me da la sombra", no sé si puedo aplicar esta acepción, dado que en el caso de la sombra se puede decir que algo es lo que hace que te dé sombra:

> *Y, para apoyar sus palabras con algún gesto simbólico, plantó los árboles que habrían de dar sombra en el futuro a la Place de la Victoire.*
>
> Alejo Carpentier, "El siglo de las luces", 1962 (Cuba).

En este tipo de construcciones, hay un sujeto de la acción "dar sombra" ("los árboles" en el ejemplo), por lo que "sombra" sería el complemento directo de "dar", usado como transitivo en este caso.

Así pues, si dices:

> Aquí nos da la sombra.

¿Se debe interpretar "la sombra" como sujeto de "dar" como intransitivo? ¿O se debe interpretar "la sombra" como complemento directo de la acción de que "algo" nos da su sombra?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> en el caso de la sombra se puede decir que algo es lo que hace que te dé sombra

Igual que en el caso del sol, donde ese algo que hace que te dé el sol es el Sol ([con mayúscula](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=sol)).

Tu duda me recuerda un poco a [la mía sobra la/le](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/22397/le-vs-la-are-both-correct-here), donde me da la sensación de que la función de cada elemento cambia según en cual quieres que recaiga la atención.

Así, si quieres centrarte en que ahí hace sombra, dirás:

> Aguanta hasta los árboles, que allí nos dará la sombra.

Y si quieres centrarte en que son los árboles los que dan la sombra:

> Aguanta hasta los árboles, que allí nos darán sombra.

En la primera, "la sombra" es sujeto de "dar" y hace el mismo papel que el sol, el aire y demás.
En la segunda, "sombra" es objeto directo de "dar", siendo el sujeto los árboles.

En cualquier caso, hay que tener en cuenta que [ni el DLE](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=YK6utrG), [ni el DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=dar) recogen el uso de "dar sombra" en el sentido en que se usa en tu literario ejemplo (cosa que me ha sorprendido, la verdad).
Si atendemos a eso, lo correcto sería "dar sombra" para la sombra, y "hacer sombra" para los árboles:

> Aguanta hasta los árboles, que allí nos dará la sombra.
>   Aguanta hasta los árboles, que allí nos harán sombra.

Comment: Además de la buena respuesta, un puntazo esa corrección sutil de "jugar un papel"→"hacer un papel", aunque yo suelo usar más "tiene un papel".

Comment: @FGSUZ ea, pues mira, una más que me llevo. :-D En todo caso, lo de "dar sombra" se podría interpretar como que la sombra es algo que el árbol "posee", y nos la entrega cuando nos ponemos en su zona de sombra. Es decir, ¿"dar" se podría interpretar ahí en su sentido básico de "entregar"?

Answer (score 1):

Yo diría que "la sombra" es el sujeto, y puede demostrarse intentando pasar la oración a voz pasiva, cosa imposible porque no hay objeto directo:

> *Aquí la sombra es dada a nosotros.

Incluso si ponemos "la sombra" en plural, veremos que el verbo ha de cambiar al plural (aunque suene un poco raro, pero no parece agramatical), con lo que se cumple la concordancia de número entre el sujeto y el verbo, confirmando que "la sombra" es el sujeto:

> Aquí nos dan las sombras.

Comment: ¿Tan incorrecta es esa pasiva? En el ejemplo de Alejo Carpentier, la oración en pasiva sería "la sombra que habría de ser dada [arrojada] por los árboles". Suena raro, pero no por eso es incorrecto. También puedes decir "aquí [los árboles] nos dan la sombra", y se elimina la concordancia entre "dar" y "la sombra".