# Why is "le" used instead of "la" in "No puedo hacerle cambiar de opinión"?

Tags: pronombres, objetos-indirectos, objetos-directos

In the following sentence, why is the indirect object pronoun "le" used instead of the direct object pronoun "la"? (The sentence is from Olly Richard´s *Short Stories in Spanish*)

> El problema es que Inma piensa que cometí un error y no puedo hacer**le** cambiar de opinión. Ella piensa que yo coqueteaba con mis clientes.

If the "le" is referring to "her" shouldn't it be "la"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["le" vs "la": are both correct here?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/22397/le-vs-la-are-both-correct-here)

Comment: Por favor, no cierren la pregunta. No es ningún duplicado, el foco puesto sobre lo que se está preguntando es distinto.

Comment: hacerle cambiar de opinión [a alguien, o sea, a ella] Spanish has hidden tricks like that.

Comment: @Lambie ¿Cuáles trucos ocultos son los que hay que descifrar?

Comment: @tac I just wrote it: hacerle cambiar de opinión [a alguien, a ella, aqui a Inma].

Comment: Por ejemplo: Quería hacerle cambiar de opinión (a Unzué) y lo conseguí», recuerda incidiendo en que iba a comenzar la temporada como delantero titular de no ser por la lesión. https://www.lavozdegalicia.es/noticia/gradario/2018/05/25/despues-lesion-jugaba-era-feliz/00031527240308302803326.htm

Comment: @Lambie De acuerdo, cito tus palabras ‘...has hidden tricks like **that**’, en esta frase, **that** es un **deíctico** y por lo tanto requiere una referencia. No veo que esté claramente indicada cuál es esa referencia. ¿Quién es *that*? ¿Dónde está el *hidden trick* que hay que descubrir? ‘Hacerle cambiar de opinión a alguien’ no es un *hidden trick* per se

Comment: @tac I just explained it again. It is directed at English speakers. It refers to what is in parenthesis.

Answer (score 4):

Although it is true that "la" is the correct form because it is the direct object (DO) (I cannot make **her** change her opinion), it is also true that "le" -- though marginally correct if we consider what DPD says below concerning the tendency, rather than the obligation, to use DO with intransitive verbs -- does not sound so bad.

This is because, although the infinitival that follows the direct object contains a prepositional phrase (cambiar **de** opinión), some native speakers might assimilate this structure to the one where "cambiar" is in turn followed by a direct object, e.g.:

- No puedo hacer**le** cambiar la propuesta. (I cannot make **her** change **the proposal**, where "her" is the DO of "make" in English while "le" is the indirect object (IO) of "hacer" in Spanish: "No puedo hacér**sela** cambiar -- the IO "le" is replaced with "se" because of the presence of the DO "la".)

Under [DPD-Leísmo](https://www.rae.es/dpd/le%C3%ADsmo), we can read the following (the bolds are mine):

> Los verbos *hacer* y *dejar*, cuando tienen sentido causativo, esto es, cuando significan, respectivamente, 'obligar' y 'permitir', siguen la misma estructura que los verbos de influencia: «verbo causativo + complemento de persona + verbo subordinado». **Tanto *hacer* como *dejar* tienden a construirse con complemento directo si el verbo subordinado es intransitivo: «Él la hizo bajar a su estudio y le mostró el cuadro»** (Aguilera Caricia [Méx. 1983]); **«Lo dejé hablar»** (Azuela Tamaño [Méx. 1973]); **y tienden a construirse con complemento indirecto cuando el segundo verbo es transitivo: «Alguien lo ayudó a incorporarse, lo estimuló y hasta le hizo tomar café»** (JmnzEmán Tramas [Ven. 1991]); **«El alcalde de la cárcel le dejaba tocar el banjo todas las mañanas»** (Cela Cristo [Esp. 1988]).

Notice that DPD says that speakers **tend** to use IO when the second verb (i.e. the infinitive, in this case) is transitive:

- **Le** hizo tomar café.

However, it does not say that: ***Lo** hizo tomar café* is wrong.

To further support my point that "la" and "lo" are better than "le" in the sentence at issue, we can replace the verb phrase "hacer cambiar de opinión" with a similar verb such as "convencer" or "persuadir" followed by a suitable adverbial:

- El problema es que Inma piensa que cometí un error y no puedo convencer**la** de lo contrario. Ella piensa que yo coqueteaba con mis clientes.
- El problema es que Inma piensa que cometí un error y no puedo persuadir**la** de que no fue así. Ella piensa que yo coqueteaba con mis clientes.

And if we want to keep the causative "hacer", we can have paraphrases such as the following:

- El problema es que Inma piensa que cometí un error y no puedo hacer**la** reflexionar. Ella piensa que yo coqueteaba con mis clientes.
- El problema es que Inma piensa que cometí un error y no puedo hacer**la** entender. Ella piensa que yo coqueteaba con mis clientes.

Since "entender" CAN be transitive, "le" can be used if a direct object is understood:

- El problema es que Inma piensa que cometí un error y no puedo hacer**le** entender (**que no fue así**). Ella piensa que yo coqueteaba con mis clientes.

Comment: But *cambiar* is transitive, so *le* is IO in the OP example.

Comment: @Gorpik puede ser transitivo o intransitivo. El razonamiento **es al revés**: debido a que se puede sustituir por *le* es O.I., en tanto es sustituible por *la* es O.D.. De hecho, podríamos tomar estas máximas como las *definiciones* de O.D. y O.I.

Comment: @Gorpik Por cierto, el hecho de no poder prescindir del ‘de’, es decir, que tenga que ser ‘cambiar de’, ya te da la pauta de que en el ejemplo del OP es intransitivo. Pero la RAE indica que ‘*se tiende a* usar el OD’, no afirman categóricamente que hay que hacerlo sí o sí

Comment: Sigo pensando esto: hacer cambiar la opinión a alguien. a ella, a él, en ciertos casos, pero no aqui, a usted.

Comment: I have made some additions that might help.

Comment: Ahora pienso que te fuiste un poco por las ramas. Yo no diría que ‘lo/la’ es mejor que ‘le’. En primer lugar, porque el leísmo existe y no es necesariamente malo, de hecho se emplea en algunas regiones y no es subestándar. En este caso, una afirmación análoga sería decir que el voseo es mejor que el tuteo o viceversa

Comment: Segundo, porque a fortiori creo que la elección depende bastante de los gustos de cada quién. Para mí, ‘hacerla’ queda mejor con ‘reflexionar’; pero ‘hacerle’ queda mejor con ‘entender’. Esto ya lo considero equivalente a la discusión sobre si el subjuntivo imperfecto es mejor con las formas -ara/-era, o bien con -ase/-ese

Comment: No se trata de irse por las ramas. Más bien se trata de un ejercicio de honestidad intelectual para tratar de entender cómo funciona la estructura. El simplismo no es siempre la mejor salida.

Comment: @tac Para mí, ‘hacerla’ queda mejor con ‘reflexionar’; pero ‘hacerle’ queda mejor con ‘entender’//No entiendo como niegas la estructura que señalé.

Comment: Con los cambios me gusta más. Ahora sí doy un voto positivo a esta respuesta.